# Redirect after a few seconds to "Thank you" page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, paypal

The second day I am playing with integrating PayPal to my website. I am trying to obtain the following behavior:

- the user click on the BUY link => is redirected to PAYPAL page (that's ok)
- the user finished payment, on the PayPal website is displayed "Thank you" page
- after 10 seconds is user redirected to "Thank you" page on my website
- to user's PayPal email is sent information about the product he bought

This is what I try to implement, but unfortunatelly I still can't find the right way to do it... My app is in Ruby on Rails, currently I am working with Sandbox and use PayPal Payments Standard.

Could you please give me some advise/tip/link, how to implement this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [PayPal Standard](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_html_wp_standard_overview)'s [Buy Now Button](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_buynow_buttons).

You can either use form created by PayPal or create own form to post to PayPal.

I'm not familiar with ruby-on-rails. However, you view the sample [here](http://cubanlinks.org/blog/2005/08/03/ruby-on-rails-paypal-ipn-code-example/). You also need to include return url and cancel url if you want to bring user back to your site.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal has a [return](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HI0709B) parameter which should work if you're using a form to send the user to their site for checkout:

> The URL to which PayPal redirects buyers’ browser after they complete
>   their payments. For example, specify a URL on your site that displays
>   a “Thank you for your payment” page. Default – PayPal redirects the
>   browser to a PayPal webpage.